# Solution of a simple vector equation

Tags: vectors

Consider the following equation

$\lambda (a+Pu)=\lambda^* (a+Pu^*)$,

where $\lambda$ and $u$ are the variables, $\lambda,\lambda^* \in \mathbb{R}$, $u, u^* ,a \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $P \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$.

Can we conclude that $\lambda=\lambda^*$ and $u=u^*$ is the only solution for this problem?

If not, what property should $P$ has, such that $\lambda=\lambda^*$ and $u=u^*$ would be the only solution...

Comment: Let $n=1$, $P=I$, $\lambda=1$, $u=1$, $\lambda^*=2$, $u^*=\frac 1 2$, and $a=0$. This is a clear counterexample to your proposition.

Comment: I have to mention that $a$ can not be a zero scalar or zero vector...

Comment: Does this also mean $u=\mathbf 0$ is also not allowed?

Comment: Please look over my new answer below. I have made it so that neither $a=\mathbf 0$ nor $u=\mathbf 0$ is being used.

Comment: Good job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to get all of the $P$s on one side and the other stuff on the other side. First, distribute the $\lambda$s:
$$\lambda a+P(\lambda u)=\lambda^* a+P(\lambda^* u^*)$$
Subtract both sides by $P(\lambda u)$ and $\lambda^* a$:
$$a(\lambda-\lambda^*)=P(\lambda^* u^*-\lambda u)$$
Now, we want to find when $\lambda=\lambda^*$ and $u=u^*$ is the only solution. In this case, it's clear we have $\mathbf 0$ on both sides.

Consider $P=\mathbf 0$. In this case, the left-hand side must be $\mathbf 0$, so if $a \neq \mathbf 0$, we have $\lambda-\lambda^*=0$, or $\lambda=\lambda^*$. However, on the right-hand side, $u$ and $u^*$ can be anything since it will come out to $\mathbf 0$. Thus, in this case, we have $\lambda=\lambda^*$ as the only solution, but not necessarily $u=u^*$.

Now, let's consider singular $P \neq \mathbf 0$. Because $P \neq \mathbf 0$, $P$ must have some non-zero vector in its range, which we will call $a$. Let's say one of the solutions to $Px=a$ is $x_a$.  If we set $\lambda=\frac 1 2$, $u=\frac 1 3x_1$, $\lambda^*=\frac 1 3$, and $u^*=x_1$, then we have found another solution to our original equation. Thus, in this case, neither $\lambda=\lambda^*$ nor $u=u^*$ is the only solutions.

Now, consider $Px=a$ for $a \neq \mathbf 0$ for non-singular $P$. Since $P$ is non-singular, there is a solution to this equation, which we'll call $x_1$. If we set $\lambda=\frac 1 2$, $u=\frac 1 3x_1$, $\lambda^*=\frac 1 3$, and $u^*=x_1$, then we have found another solution to our original equation. Thus, in this case, neither $\lambda=\lambda^*$ nor $u=u^*$ is the only solutions.

Thus, there is no case where your equation only has the solution $\lambda=\lambda^*$ and $u=u^*$. There will always be another solution.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\lambda (a+Pu)=\lambda^* (a+Pu^*) \iff \\
(\lambda -\lambda^*) a = P(\lambda^* u^* - \lambda u)
$$
and this leaves open more possibilities than just $\lambda = \lambda^*$ and $u = u^*$, which would be an instance of $0 = 0$ on both sides.
But there could be other vector equalities, of course.